# vscode extension: How can I add data like linenumber, text to a view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I added a view container and views to the package.json:

```
"viewsContainers": {
  "activitybar": [
    {
      "id": "cnc-views-container",
      "title": "CNC",
      "icon": "ISGCncEditor.png"
    }
  ]
},
"views": {
  "cnc-views-container": [
    {
      "id": "cnc-view-tools",
      "name": "Tools"
    },
    {
      "id": "cnc-view-programs",
      "name": "Programs"
    }
  ]
},
```

Now I want to make a regex search in the editor text, for example "T\d+" and the results should be shown as links in the "cnc-view-tools" view.
For example:
Linenumber: 102, Text: T2 D2
And when I click the link in my view the cursor should jump to the linenumber in the text editor.

Is this possible?
Here is an example cnc file.

```
%SysMillFaceDemo.nc

; Facemilling
T9 D9                                               ( Tool data )
M6                                                  ( Tool change )
G00 G17 G90 F2000 M03 S6000                         ( Technology data )
G00 Z50                                             ( Go to z start position )
G00 X-50 Y0                                         ( position near workpiece, mill tool is outside the part )

T10 D10
G00 X200

M30
```

The cnc-view-tools should contain two entries after the regex search:

4, T9 D9
10, T10 D10

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/rioj7/html-related-links or a similar extension for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to filter content in a registered sidebar view, right? With the standard content (a treeview) this is not possible. If you have a web view there you can implement custom HTML search/filtering. There's nothing built-in that would give you this funtionality.1

Comment: Ok thanks. So I will use an webview. Do you have a link or Information how can I do implement custom HTML search/filtering?
I am on this point panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
The function getWebviewContent is empty at the moment...
I think in this function i should make a html string from the search list?

Comment: It might already be enough to set `enableFindWidget` to true when you create the web view.